# How to display an html file using a controller in the OpenERP framework?

Tags: odoo

I am trying to create a new module in which I have to display an html view that contains one select box. On `change event` I have to display a dynamic text box. I have to develop a template for it.

Is it possible and - if yes - then how to create such a template?

Comment: i dont understand that question fully. can you give more information please? maybe some screenshots with examples or something like that.

Comment: I had write a controller that can simply show content of xml file having template                                                                                                                             @http.route(['/say_hi'], type="http", multilang=True)
    def website_customer(self):
        values = {
        'id1':5
        }
       
        return request.website.render("convertor.demo", values)           My .xml file contains                                              <template id="references" inherit_id="convertor.demo" name="Partner References">------------------</template>

Comment: sorry my controller expertise isn't that great so far, so i can't help on that end :-(